# Entity design and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity, base-class

Im thinking about the design of entity baseclasses for a larger application and would like some opinions. Primarily if what specified is the way it has to be done or if there are a cleaner way.

In the solution i have some `baseclass` variants which all entities will inherit. The relations can be specified as below:

```
EntityBase//the primary baseclass containing name and id + other stuff 
NestedEntityBase:EntityBase //(if class will be able to contain lists of itself)

VersionedEntityBase:EntityBase //(Some parameters specific for versioned entities)  
VersionNestedEntityBase:NestedEntityBase// (versioned AND nested)

CurrentStateEntityBase:VersionedEntityBase// (the currentstate objects) 
VersionStateEntityBase:VersionedEntityBase// (old objects, saved when surrentstate objects change)

CurrentStateNestedEntityBase:VersionNestedEntityBase// (the currentstate objects) 
VersionStateNestedEntityBase:VersionNestedEntityBase //(old objects, saved when surrentstate objects change)
```

This unfortunately creates some code duplication since multiple inheritance isnt possible.

It will also set the divisions for the generic services and generic controller baseclasses.

Is this how it must be handled or am i missing some clever way of doing this more effectively?

Comment: why not name `Nested` as `List` if it will contain list of itself! also you can use interface

Comment: The two parts that Nested class contains is an icollection of its own type (Named Versions) and a Current property of its own type (entity code-first). 

CurrentState and VersionSTate does similarbut version contains Parent of its own type and icollection 'Children' of its own type.

I agree regarding interfaces(wich i use) and  they give me more choices. But my main issue was how to populate the interface instances with as little code duplication as possible.
 
But i cant find a way to avoid duplication, the upper level entitybase properties would have to be duplicated.

Comment: But perhaps it is unavoidable during the circumstances?

Comment: Yeah i would like to add something regarding your comment on interfaces. I thought about the post by Rayende (http://ayende.com/blog/4769/code-review-guidelines-avoid-inheritance-for-properties) and can interpret it (as ive seen some others suggesting similar and perhaps you?) is to have one large baseclass and control it using interfaces. It seems like a good idea on some levels, but as far as i know ill then would have to scrap entity code first and unsure of the automap support.

Comment: I voted your answer up because relieving some of the inheritance with interfaces (thus living with some property duplication) seems to be the best way i could find to reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

How about Decorator design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

It allows to extend class hierarchy with some new behaviour without duplicating
this whole hierarchy every time. Also it adds benefit of extending behaviour in
runtime (not only at compile time).

Comment: Deleted my comment because it was incorrect, i misunderstood the decoratorpattern at first glance. I agree it could be an option in certain cases but since this concerns database entity inheritance i cant see a good way (atleast now) of implementing this pattern. For other areas though i could see the usefulness of this.